# React.js 0.14 - Required prop `clientId` was not specified in `WelcomePage`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**In my APP, which is the parent component of my react-router, I have this:**

```jsx
export default class APP extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clientId: 'A134567897',
      ..........................
    };
  }

  componentDidCount() {
    CompanyInfo.getGenlInfo()
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState(data);
      });
  }

  renderChild = () =>
    React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      // this needs to be passed to all child routes
      ...this.state
    });

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Header { ...this.state } />

        {/* This is where the dynamic content goes */}
        { React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChild) }

        <Footer { ...this.state } />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

In my router, a path of '/' brings up the WelcomePage (main page) component.

The WelcomePage component **does appear** as expected, and **this.props.clientId does have a value**, but if I code on the WelcomePage ....

```jsx
WelcomePage.propTypes = {
  clientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

> **Required prop `clientId` was not specified in `WelcomePage`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.**

I thought I took care of passing the clientId props to the WelcomePage through the APP's renderChild() method with '...this.state', didn't I?

Does anyone see where the error lies? Again, the ***clientID value does successfully pass to the WelcomePage***, but I receive an error if I make it required on the WelcomePage.

Many Thanks

Comment: `propTypes` is for `props` and has nothing to do with `state`.

Comment: So how would I pass the clientId state to the WelcomePage as a prop?

Comment: As any other prop: `<WelcomePage clientId=... />` ?

Comment: Can't do that. That section is dynamic and changes per route path.

Comment: Btw, why do you use `React.Children.map` if you don't use argument that is passed to `renderChild`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `.isRequired` on `propTypes` for route components.

This is because React checks `propTypes` at the time of element creation. React Router will initially create all of the route component elements with just the React Router props; by the time you get to the `cloneElement` call, this validation has already happened and failed.

We've recently added a note to the upgrade guide detailing this: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#routehandler

For more details see: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4494#issuecomment-125068868